# Hibernate 4.3.0.Final: select on multiple table

Tags: hibernate

I'm using Hibrnate core 4.3.0.

I have 2 table; table A is related M:N with itself by table B

I have this structure:

**TABLE A**:

- ***ID***: primary key
- ***NAME***: name of the element
- ***STATE***: state of the element

**TABLE B**:

- ***ID_SOURCE***: FK to table A
- ***ID_TARGET***: FK to table A
- ***RELATION_NAME***: name of the relation type

In table B the primary key is a composite one composed by ID_SOURCE and ID_TARGET.

Now I have been able in creating all the classes correctly mapped; now I'ld love to make the following query:

```
select
    ID,
    NAME,
    STATE
from
    TABLE_A this1, TABLE_B src1_
where
    src1_.ID_SOURCE=4018
    and src1_.ID_TARGET=this1.ID
```

Now I know I may use HQL and/or native SQL in order to create such kind of query, but I'ld love to use Hibernate Criteria or better DetachedCriteria

Is it possible to create such query by using DetachedCriteria?

Thank you

Angelo

Comment: Have you tried? What fails or what do you fail to understand? Because right now the answer is "yes".

Comment: @mabi yes I tried several combination but unsuccessufully and I'm getting more and more sure that by using DetachedCriteria it's not possibile to create such query....do you have any code snippet I can take inspiration

Answer (score 0):

I guess I found the way to do it by using the setFetchMode; basically I wrote this DetachedCriteria (note: I mapped the relationship fields with `fetch=FetchType.LAZY`):

```
DetachedCriteria dc = DetachedCriteria.forClass(B.class);
dc.setFetchMode("tgtA", FetchMode.JOIN);
dc.add(Property.forName("srcA.id").eq(4018l));
```

This has been transformed by hibernate in the following query:

```
select
    b.ID_SOURCE,
    b.ID_TARGET,
    b.RELATION_NAME,
    a.ID,
    a.NAME,
    a.STATE
from
    B b 
inner join
    A a on b.ID_TARGET=a.ID_ENTITY 
where
    b.ID_SOURCE=?
```

Now I was wondering what are the performances when I execute this kind of query....is this the right way to do it?

Thank you

Angelo